# Remove a div of a particular class

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have some divs:

```
<h4>Ruby on Rails</h4>
<div class="progress-bar green">
    <span style="width: 90%"></span>
</div>
<h4>HTML/CSS</h4>
<div class="progress-bar orange">
    <span style="width: 80%"></span>
</div>
<h4>PHP</h4>
<div class="progress-bar orange">
    <span style="width: 60%"></span>
</div>
<h4>Javascript</h4>
<div class="progress-bar red">
    <span style="width: 40%"></span>
</div>
```

I want to use php to remove any div appearing with class "progress-bar" in html code of a page.
Like:

If I have file_html.php with some code, I will get it's html code using this line:

```
$html = file_get_contents('file_html.php');
```

And now I want to remove the progress-bar divs appearing in the code.
Is this possible, if yes how can I solve problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you using to parse the html or are you hoping to treat it as a string?

Comment: @yardpenalty not if he want's to do this server side in php?

Comment: Right that's why I removed the comment. If he is always getting file contents he could use jQuery on `$(document).ready` tho

Comment: I am trying to treat it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [the `DOMDocument` class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Since [you cannot remove an element from a list while iterating](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#902920), then build up a to-be-removed array and drop those after searching.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/gqIo2)

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('file_html.php');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $class = $div->getAttribute('class');
    if (strpos($class, 'progress-bar') !== false) {
        $domElemsToRemove[] = $div;
    }
}

foreach( $domElemsToRemove as $domElement ){ 
    $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement); 
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><h4>Ruby on Rails</h4>

<h4>HTML/CSS</h4>

<h4>PHP</h4>

<h4>Javascript</h4>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove the whole div.

Comment: Yep, i want to remove whole div. Sorry the title of question was wrong.

Comment: @user6803164 whoops, sorry I read the question too fast. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am receiving: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\index.php(16): DOMNode->removeChild(Object(DOMElement)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\index.php on line 16

How to solve ?

Comment: @user6803164 that's bizarre. you must have some extra code in there. [Here's a working fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/gqIo2)

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I tried that fiddle on PC. It worked, but I tried with my real php html page which is huge, it shows error.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII THANKS ALOT IT FINALLY WORKED.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I replaced $div->parentNode->removeChild($domElement); with this $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement); .

Answer (score 0):

You should do this using an HTML parser:

Using https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

```
$dom = new Dom;
$html = file_get_contents('file_html.php');
$dom->load($html);
foreach($a as $dom->find('.progress-bar')) {
    $a->delete();
    unset($a);
}
echo $dom;
```

If you want to do it using string (not recommended):

```
echo preg_replace('/(<div class=.*?progress\-bar.*?<\/div>)/s', '', $html);
```

You could make this regex more/less restrictive depending on your use-case.

Comment: Received error: 
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\index.php on line 7

Comment: What is line 7 in index.php?

Comment: foreach($a as $dom->find('.progress-bar'))

Comment: You might have to upgrade your version of PHP. The library supports php 5.6, 7.0, and hhvm 2.3.

Comment: Still not working for 5.6 as well as 7.0(Fiddle: https://3v4l.org/oRUHF)

Comment: `$elements = $dom->find('.progress-bar');` `foreach ($a as $elements)`. You will have to install the dom parser too for it to work. https://3v4l.org/2C0te

Comment: I got html parser with composer and ran it. But, it shows the unchanged output. I mean, the divs are not removed. http://image.prntscr.com/image/9696d1170c764d1b9d5bcd67c0ca8a98.jpg and is showing 
Notice: Undefined variable: a in E:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\index.php on line 188

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\index.php on line 188
Errors in background.

Comment: Try getting rid of `unset($a)` but I see that the other solution has already worked for you :)